# Why does my filtering of queryset on valid pk returns full queryset?

Tags: python, django

As far as I understand, querysets can always be filtered on. However, if I create this queryset filtering breaks:

```
set_synonyms = Compound.objects.filter(synonyms__name__icontains=query_string)
```

It is a proper queryset:

```
<QuerySet [<Compound: 2-[4-(2-methylpropyl)phenyl]propanoic acid>, <Compound: 2-[4-(2-methylpropyl)phenyl]propanoic acid>, <Compound: 2-[4-(2-methylpropyl)phenyl]propanoic acid>, <Compound: 2-[4-(2-methylpropyl)phenyl]propanoic acid>,  '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

and I can get the pk of any element of the queryset, e.g.:

```
pk=set_synonyms.first().pk
```

(pk has the value 76)
But when I filter on it, the whole queryset is returned:

```
set_synonyms.filter(pk=pk)
```

just returns the whole queryset `set_synonyms`. And using `set_synonyms.get(pk=pk)` raises `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception (because it returns the whole queryset `set_synonyms`).

Possible relevant information: the relation between `Compound` and `Synonym` models is a 1-to-many (1 compound having many synonyms).

```
class Synonym(MixinPubChemCompound, models.Model):
    """Model definition for synonym naming of compound"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=999, db_index=True, null=True)
    compound = models.ForeignKey(
        Compound, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='synonyms')
    retrieved_from = models.ForeignKey(
        generic_models.Reference, related_name='synonyms',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT)
class Compound(MixinPubChemCompound, models.Model):
    cid = models.IntegerField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    iupac_name = models.ForeignKey(
        IupacName, on_delete=models.PROTECT, unique=False)
```

Comment: are you assigning set_synonyms.filter(pk=pk) to anything?

Comment: yes I am, but that is not the issue here. I found out that it is because the filtering `Compound.objects.filter(synonyms__name__icontains=query_string)` returns a couple of time the same compound. And thus the same pk and thus calling `get` fails. This was obscured to me due to some following querying I did. Apparently, I needed SO as my rubber duck to find the solution myself.

Comment: Very nice, well done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there were multiple synonyms of the same compound matching the querystring. So the resulting queryset had duplicates of the same compound. Thus filtering on the pk's of that queryset returns multiple instances in the queryset ( in this particular case, the whole queryset). Adding `distinct()` solves the problem. So, replacing

```
set_synonyms = Compound.objects.filter(synonyms__name__icontains=query_string)
```

with

```
set_synonyms = Compound.objects.filter(synonyms__name__icontains=query_string).distinct()
```

solves the issue.